# How do I create a window like that of CleanMyMac X in tkinter where some parts of the screen are outside the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

[CleanMyMacX image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fUlh.png)

As you can see, some of the buttons are outside of the window, and the window's title isn't visible. I am wondering if this is possible to do in python tkinter, and if so, how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a new window, remove its title bar and place it in the correct place? It will take a lot of coding but it can be done

Comment: Hmm, maybe that can be done, I'll try. Thanks for the suggestion!